# Sending REST Requests with Symfony2

Tags: rest, symfony, request, put

Is there any bundle that can send REST requests to external web pages? I need PUT and DELETE as well as PATCH (http method).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are looking for this bundle:
https://github.com/CircleOfNice/CiRestClientBundle

```
$restClient = $this->container->get('ci.restclient');

$restClient->get('http://www.someUrl.com');
$restClient->post('http://www.someUrl.com', 'somePayload');
$restClient->put('http://www.someUrl.com', 'somePayload');
$restClient->delete('http://www.someUrl.com');
$restClient->patch('http://www.someUrl.com', 'somePayload');

$restClient->head('http://www.someUrl.com');
$restClient->options('http://www.someUrl.com', 'somePayload');
$restClient->trace('http://www.someUrl.com');
$restClient->connect('http://www.someUrl.com');
```